# Can I define a time zone for the Quarkus Scheduler

Tags: java, quarkus

I need to execute a method in my Quarkus application at a fixed time in a given time zone. I found the "quarkus-scheduler" extension, which provides the "@Scheduled" annotation, but this does not seem to offer any possibility to set the time zone.

Both the Java EE "@Schedule" and the Spring "@Scheduled" annotation have a corresponding parameter, but how can I achieve this in Quarkus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment. Quarkus scheduler is using the default time-zone of the JVM running the app. I've created a new issue to track this feature request: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/25159.

Comment: The feature is implemented now: https://quarkus.io/guides/scheduler-reference#time-zones